# Angular 2 post request to php file

Tags: php, http, angular

I'm trying to send a post request from angular 2 to a php file.

Unfortunetly, when trying to `var_dump($_POST)`, I see an empty array.

This is my angular 2 post:

```
addPerson(name)
{
    let body = JSON.stringify({
                name : name,    
        });
    this.http.request(this.BASE_URL + "mode=add", {body:body, method: 'POST'})
      .subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log(response.json());
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
  }
```

In my PHP File I just tried to `var_dump($_POST)`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you used `http.request`. You could call `HTTP` post method directly, that seems simpler and more readable.

```
this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + "mode=add", body)
```

Comment: I used http.request becaues angular 2 custom request options with fixed url doesn't work on the http.post method

Comment: What do you mean with "fixed url"?

Comment: `export class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

  merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
    options.url = 'http://my-url.com' + options.url;
 if (options.method === 1) {
 let headers = new Headers();
 headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    options.headers = headers;
   }
    return super.merge(options);
  }

}`
and I have the same output (empty array) with the `this.http.post method`